# Escaping periods correctly in Typeahead query

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, typeahead

Got a Typeahead search box on my site where users can search names of kids including initials.

Whenever someone searches for example 'A. Stark', the query will cut off at the period, and only search 'A'.

JavaScript code:

```
var kids = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace(d);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/search/kids/%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});
```

Rails code:

```
  def kids
    render json: current_client.kids.active.
        where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%").
        limit(SEARCH_LIMIT).map {|k| {id: k.id, name: k.name, type: 'kids'}}.to_json
  end
```

The problem seems to come from the JS side where the variable `%QUERY`is replaced by the query unescaped in the URL, where a period ofcourse has a different context. Not sure how to solve this though

Comment: your code looks ok, I just checked my app(using typeahead as well) and I can search things with `.` no problem at all. So in rails log do you see `params[:query]` get trimmed off `.`?If it is then maybe params[:query] is sanitized somewhere?

Comment: if you paste your typeahead initialisation code here, it may help the debugging

Comment: %QUERY gets replaced by the query, so with the example given in the question this would become `/search/kids/a.stark`. The Rails router then considers the last part as a format and strips it from the params. I could probably rewrite it to `/search/kids?query=a.stark` which should work, but I like the clean rails router.